# Error in python IDE installation

Tags: software-installation, python, matlab

I am simple Ubuntu user, I tried to install python IDE-spyder just to see how things work there, but unfortunately I ran into a problem that is something related to matlab.
[image: a dialog that ask for matlab installation folder]

Now this dialog appear on my screen everytime i startup my system and is very annoying. It seems like the installation stuck somewhere.
Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Was it install via `apt` or `apt-get`?

Comment: i tried installing it from Ubuntu software center

Comment: Try uninstalling it from there.

Comment: That looks like something related to the `matlab-support` package - not the `python-spyder` package. Did you install that as well?

Comment: ya. I installed Matlab and problem Solved.

Comment: FYI, installation was stuck and so Ubuntu software center was also not working, neither 'apt remove' , installing Matlab works for me. Thank you All for your supports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing MATLAB, then try again.

MATLAB probably is a dependency

Comment: this was a long process, but it WORKS!!.

Comment: Then it might be helpful for others if you marked my answer as correct (I know this is really late, but whatever)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/) as an IDE for python.